# Passing generic objects to Rust and passing back to C++ for destruction after usage

Tags: c++, rust

I want to send buffers from C++ to Rust, read them in Rust and destruct them on C++ when they're not needed anymore.

This is the function that I made to receive:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn smol_stack_smol_socket_send(
    smol_stack: &mut SmolStackType,
    socket_handle_key: usize,
    data: *mut u8,
    len: usize,
    endpoint: CIpEndpoint,
) -> u8 {
```

I want to receive a pointer to `uint8_t` data but I also dont think I need to allocate this data myself using `new uint8_t[size]`. For example, I might do it with a string:

```
std::string* s = new std::string("hello");
```

and then simply pass `s.c_str()` as `uint8_t*` to Rust. I cannot simply call `delete[] s.c_str()`, I need to delete the `s` string on C++ side. So, I'm thinking of adding another 2 parameters to my function `smol_stack_smol_socket_send`. One is a pointer to the object that owns the `uint8_t` buffer (in this case, the string, but could be another), and the other is the pointer to the function that receives this object and destructs.

I thought of something like receiving the string/object as a void pointer in Rust, but I don't know if it's possible. Also, the second parameter, the function that destructs, needs to be a function that acts on generic data also, because I could pass a different object than a string, that owns the data.

What would be an elegant and safe solution here?

Comment: Don't use `std::string` for a buffer, the small string optimization is going to cause issues sooner rather than later. Use a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` instead. And you don't need to `new` the `string` or `vector`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You do need to new the string (or vector) if you're passing ownership of it to rust. But you don't if you're just operating on its buffer.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: Yes, but you can't `new` the string, pass the internal buffer, and then `delete[]` the internal buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it you have at least two possible paths. Which one works for you will depend a lot on how these calls all fit together.

This simplest is to just consider the data passed from C++ to rust to remain owned by C++. i.e. `smol_stack_smol_socket_send` is expected to not destroy the buffer passed to it. That job falls to the caller of `smol_stack_smol_socket_send`.

The rust code might look like:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn simpler_function(
    data: *mut u8,
    len: usize,
) { .. }
```

Then the C++ code would look like:

```
void with_string() {
   std::string buffer("Hello World");
   simpler_function(buffer.c_str(), buffer.length());
   // C++ destroys the string here.
}

void with_newed_buffer() {
   char* buffer=new char[10];
   buffer[0]='A';
   buffer[1]=0;
   simpler_function(buffer, 2);
   delete [] buffer;
}
```

An alternative approach would be to pass a callback to the function to handle destroying the buffer

```
type Destructor = extern "C" fn(*mut c_void);

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn core_function(
    data: *mut u8,
    len: usize,
    calback_data: *mut c_void
    destructor: Destructor
) {
   ..
   // We're done with the data - destroy it
   destructor(callback_data);
}
```

Now in C++ the code can look like this...

```
void delete_buffer(void* buffer) {
    delete [] (char*)buffer;
}

void with_newed_buffer() {
   char* buffer=new char[10];
   buffer[0]='A';
   buffer[1]=0;
   simpler_function(buffer, 2, buffer, delete_buffer);
}
```

IMO you should always prefer the first approach. The only case where this doesn't work is when rust needs to take ownership (and hence control the lifetime) of a C++ object. Typically this means storing it somewhere in a rust collection etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going with the second approach because Rust does not use the dtaa instantly, it stores on a collection

Comment: @LucasZanella You probably already realise it, but in that case, make sure to store the destructor and the `c_void*` with the data - so that you can destroy it at the right time. (Presumably not inside the `smol_stack_smol_socket_send` function as in the example)

Answer (score 1):

If you decide that Rust needs to take ownership of the object, you might want to write a wrapper that implements [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html), to free the object automatically:

```rust
struct Whatever {
    data: *mut u8,
    len: usize,
    object: *mut c_void,
    destructor: extern "C" fn(*mut c_void),
}

impl Drop for Whatever {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.destructor(self.object)
    }
}
```